# Adding CPT changes entire layout of my site except for the archive of that CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, themes

I am writing a plugin that adds a CPT called Contest.  The problem is that the entire layout of the site is changed when I activate the plugin.  The odd thing is that the changes are applied to everything EXCEPT for the contest archive.  When I deactivate the plugin, the site returns to it's original layout.  I am currently using the 2016 theme.  To see what I mean, look below...

[image]

Why does this happen?  Here is the code for my plugin...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyPlugin
Description:  Time-based competition manager that allows you to control contests with starting images, running dates, entries, winners, and prizes.
Version: 0.1
Author: Me
*/

function imgw_cpts(){

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Contests',
        'singular_name' => 'Contest',
        'menu_name' => 'Contests',
        'name_admin_bar' => 'Contest',
        'add_new' => 'Add Contest',
        'add_new_item' => 'New Contest',
        'new_item' => 'New Contest',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Contest',
        'view_item' => 'View Contest',
        'all_items' => 'All Contests',
        'search_items' => 'Search for a Contest',
        'not_found' => 'There are no contests right now!',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'There are no contests in the trash right now!'
    );
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-awards',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'contests'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title')
    );
    register_post_type( 'contest', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'imgw_cpts' );

function imgw_meta_boxes(){
    add_meta_box( 'contest-dates', __('Running Dates'), 'imgw_dates_metabox', 'contest' );
    add_meta_box( 'contest-description', __('Description/Rules'), 'imgw_description_editor', 'contest' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'imgw_meta_boxes' );

function imgw_dates_metabox($object){

      wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");
?>
<div>
<label>Starting Date</label>
<input type="date" name="contest-starting-date" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-starting-date", true); ?>"> at <input type="time" name="contest-starting-time" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-starting-time", true); ?>">
<label>Ending Date</label>
<input type="date" name="contest-ending-date" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-ending-date", true); ?>"> at <input type="time" name="contest-ending-time" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "contest-ending-time", true); ?>">
</div>

<?php
} 

function imgw_description_editor($object){ ?>
<textarea name="contest-description" rows="10" cols="100" placeholder="Enter a description or rules..."><?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'contest-description', true); ?></textarea>
<?php    
}
function imgw_save_contest_meta( $post_id, $post ) {

    global $post;

  if($post->post_type == 'contest')

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-description', $_POST['contest-description'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-starting-date', $_POST['contest-starting-date'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-starting-time', $_POST['contest-starting-time'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-ending-date', $_POST['contest-ending-date'] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'contest-ending-time', $_POST['contest-ending-time'] );

} // end save_meta_data

add_action('save_post', 'imgw_save_contest_meta', 10, 3);

function imgw_contest_content( $content ){

    global $post;

    if($post->post_type == 'contest'){
        $content = "[imgw-contest id=\"".$post->ID."\"][/imgw-contest]";
        return $content;  

    }      

    wp_die('Hello!');

}

add_filter('the_content', 'imgw_contest_content');

function featured_image_requirement() {

    global $typenow;

    if("contest" == $typenow){

         if(!has_post_thumbnail()) {

              //wp_die( 'You forgot to set the featured image. Click the back button on your browser and set it.' ); 

         } 

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_post_update', 'featured_image_requirement' );

add_filter( 'post_class', 'imgw_contest_class' );

function imgw_contest_class( $classes ) {

  /* Get the current post ID. */
  $post_id = get_the_ID();

  /* If we have a post ID, proceed. */
  if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) {

    /* Get the custom post class. */
    $post_class = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'contest-description', true );

    /* If a post class was input, sanitize it and add it to the post class array. */
    if ( !empty( $post_class ) )
      $classes[] = sanitize_html_class( $post_class );
  }

  return $classes;
}

function imgw_shortcodes( $atts ){

    extract( $atts );

    $starting_date = date(get_option('date_format'), strtotime(get_post_meta($id, 'contest-starting-date', true)));
    $starting_time = date(get_option('time_format'), strtotime(get_post_meta($id, 'contest-starting-time', true)));
    $ending_date = date(get_option('date_format'), strtotime(get_post_meta($id, 'contest-ending-date', true)));
    $ending_time = date(get_option('time_format'), strtotime(get_post_meta($id, 'contest-ending-time', true)));
    $description = get_post_meta($id, 'contest-description', true);

    $status_colors = array('Active' => 'green', 'Expired' => 'red', 'Pending' => 'gold');

    ?>
    <p><label style="font-weight: bold;">Dates:</label> <?php echo $starting_date;?> at <?php echo $starting_time;?> - <?php echo $ending_date;?> at <?php echo $ending_time;?></p>
    <p><label style="font-weight: bold;">Status:</label> <span style="color:<?php echo $status_colors[contest_status($id)]; ?>"><?php echo contest_status($id);?></span></p>
    <p><label style="font-weight: bold;">Description:</label> <?php echo $description; ?></p>

    <h2>Entries</h2>
    <p><a href="<?php echo comments_link();?>">Submit Entry</a></p>

<?php }

add_shortcode('imgw-contest', 'imgw_shortcodes');

function contest_status($id){

    $starting_date = get_post_meta($id, 'contest-starting-date', true);
    $starting_time = get_post_meta($id, 'contest-starting-time', true);
    $ending_date = get_post_meta($id, 'contest-ending-date', true);
    $ending_time = get_post_meta($id, 'contest-ending-time', true);

    $start = strtotime($starting_date." ".$starting_time);
    $end = strtotime($ending_date." ".$ending_time);

    $now = time();

    if($now > $start && $now < $end){

        $status = 'Active';

    } else if($now > $end){

        $status = 'Expired';

    } else if($now < $start){

        $status = 'Pending';

    }

    return $status;

}

?>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `wp_die('Hello!');`?

Comment: Silly me.... forgot that I put that there to test if the filter was being called.... thanks lol